# Altium update from schematic - delete and add component constantly

Tags: altium

When I issue an engineering change order to update my PCB from the schematic window, 2 components are always deleted and added every time.  How can I stop this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Project->Component Links, and read [this](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/WorkspaceManager_Dlg-ComfirmCompMatchesForm%28%28Edit+Component+Links%29%29_AD).

[image]